# invalid load key, '\x16' while using WEBASSEMBLY with pickle

Tags: python, pickle, webassembly

I made a basic programme using python, pygame and pickle.

I deployed it on WEBASSEMBLY to be able to ply it on a browser directly.

My game works fine on local but when I tried to use play using webassembly I get the error

```
def threaded_client(conn, player):
    try:
        conn.send(pickle.dumps(players[player]))
        while True:
            raw_data = conn.recv(2048)
            print("Data received. Deserializing...", raw_data)
            print("pickle.loads(raw_data) :", pickle.loads(raw_data))
            data = pickle.loads(raw_data)
            print(f"Received data from player {player}: {data}")
            if not data:
                break
            players[player] = data
            reply = players[:player] + players[player+1:]
            print("pickle.dumps(reply) :", pickle.dumps(reply))
            conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(reply))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error handling client {player}: {e}")
    finally:
        print(f"Connection with player {player} closed")
        conn.close()
```

So, I get the error:

```
"invalid load key, '\x16'" when pickle.loads(raw_data)
```

The raw_data I am receiving (with `webassembly`) looks like this:
`b'\x16\x03\x01\x027\x01\x00\x023\x03\x03\xcah\xbdT\x9b\xbf\x87\x02z\x89\x80\x01\xc4>s\xd3da\x96\xae6\x16\xdd\xa8 \x89\xa0\x80\x97?\xa1\xd8'` .........................'

However, while I am running it locally i receive raw_data like:
`b'\x80\x04\x95\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08entities\x94\x8c\x0cOtherPlayers\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(\x8c\x01x\x94K2\x8c\x01y\x94K2\x8c\tdirection\x94\x8c\x04down\x94\x8c\x0bindex_image\x94K\x00\x8c\x11spritesheet_index\x94\x8c\x08foot_red\x94\x8c\x10current_map_name\x94\x8c\x07paradis\x94\x8c\x04role\x94\x8c\x05mouse\x94\x8c\x04name\x94\x8c\x07chicken\x94ub`'.

So, I guess the problem is this line where I send the raw_data to the server:

```
self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
```

As if the version of pickle was different in `webassembly` or was not working the same way...

Comment: You could try to play around with the `protocol` argument of `pickle.dumps`. E. g. `protocol=1` should use an older and more compatible data format.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it did not work. 

I also tried to replace pickle.dumps and pickle.loads by json.dumps and json.loads but I still run into the same kind of issue... :

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 11: invalid continuation byte

I really don't know how to commmunicate from webassembly to a server using socket grrrr